# Loop through all input item which aren't a filetype

Tags: javascript, loops, validation

I have the following code which is being used as validation on input fields. However, I'm getting stuck as it's checking input filetype fields as well, which I don't want it to do. Is there a way of getting it to ignore an file input field?

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      
     //I only want the following condition statement to run if the current element is not a file field. 
      
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but  you should consider using `for (let i = 0;...` rather than defining `i` outside of the loop - `let` will define your variable only inside your loop. As you have it at the moment, `i` will change value even outside your for loop, which could lead to unexpected behavior in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `querySelectorAll` instead, and use `:not([type="file"])`:

```
y = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input:not([type="file"])');
```

You can also consider making the fields `required` to help improve UI, in addition to the Javascript.

To refactor a bit, consider using more meaningful variable names, and using `classList.add` so as to avoid adding duplicate class attributes to elements:

```
function validateForm() {
  const thisTab = document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[currentTab];
  const inputs = thisTab.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="file"])');
  let valid = true;
  for (const input of inputs) {
    if (input.value === '') {
      input.classList.add('invalid');
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    thisTab.classList.add('finish');
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Comment: Awesome...thanks. Points noted. When you see the code working it all makes sense! Many thanks.

Comment: Yes...will do. I'm quite new on here so working it out :-0